# What is best practice for running mysqlcheck on a MySQL 5.7 server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

What is best practice for running mysqlcheck on a MySQL 5.7 server?  How often should I schedule it to run?

Comment: This may be a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you're using InnoDB, which you really, **really** should be, it's largely irrelevant. It's mostly a tool to deal with MyISAM tables that can crumble and fall apart for various reasons. This is like the difference between brittle, non-journaled filesystems like FAT and ext2 vs. more modern ones like ext4 that don't require the same aggressive checking.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Also, I was not aware of dba.stackexchange.com. I will join that too!